# Separability=$T_1$ for TVS?

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let a topological linear space be defined by the continuity of the linear operations only. I read on an Italian language functional analysis book, which doesn't show the proof, that any locally convex, locally bounded, *separable* topological linear space is normable.

In Rudin's *Functional Analysis*, which supposes $T_1$ to hold in a topological linear space, I find that any locally convex, locally bounded topological linear space is normable.

Does it mean that $T_1$ and separability are equivalent in such spaces? I'm inclined to suppose that *separable topological linear space* might be used in the sense of *topological linear $T_1$-space* rather than *topolgical linear space containing an everywhere dense countable subset*, as when *separable topology* is found as a synonym of *topology satisfying axiom* $T_1$.

Thank you so much for any answer!!!

Comment: I would highly suspect, that in your first case the author means *separated*, not separable. In fact, the indiscrete topology fulfills all your requirements in your first section, but is not normable.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! $T_1$ equates separate for topological vector spaces, indeed. I also find that a sufficient condition for the natural map of the space $E$ into the bidual space $E^{\ast\ast}$, defined by $\pi:x\mapsto \psi_x$, where $\psi_x:f\mapsto f(x)$, to be injective is that $E$ be locally convex and *separable*, while I have found a $T_1$-space in other resources...

Comment: Sorry again, but even for the injectivity only $T_1$ (and locally convex) is sufficent. You may take the indiscrete topology again as a counterexample.

Comment: $\infty$ thanks! Very interesting: so there is a misprint or mistranslation in my Italian language translation of Kolmogorov-Fomin's from Russian.